# Bad json encoding

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to parse in json a txt file content. This is the file content:

```
[19-02-2016 16:48:45.505547] [info] System done. 
 0: array(
  'ID' => 'Example 2'
 )
```

Now this is my code for parse the file:

```
$fh = fopen($file, "r");
$content = array(); 
$content["trace"] = array();

while ($line = fgets($fh))
{
     $raw = preg_split("/[\[\]]/", $line); 
     $entry = array();
     $entry["date"] = trim($raw[1]);
     $entry["type"] = trim($raw[3]);
     $entry["message"] = trim($raw[4]);
     $content["trace"][] = $entry;
}

fclose($fh);
return $content;
```

and this is what is returned from `$content`:

```
{
    "trace": [{
        "date": "19-02-2016 16:48:45.505547"
        "type": "info"
        "message": "System done."
    }, {
        "date": ""
        "type": ""
        "message": ""
    }, {
        "date": ""
        "type": ""
        "message": ""
    }, {
        "date": ""
        "type": ""
        "message": ""
    }]
}
```

---

**UPDATE I'm expecting this:**

```
{
    "trace": [{
        "date": "19-02-2016 16:48:45.505547"
        "type": "info"
        "message": "System done."
        "ID": Example 2
    }]
}
```

how you can see the array is saw as a new line and the code create other empty array in the while without content. I just want create new index later `message` and put the array content, how I can achieve this?

*UPDATE WITH MORE CONTENT IN FILE*

```
[19-02-2016 16:57:17.104504] [info] system done. 
 0: array(
   'ID' => 'john foo'
 )
[19-02-2016 16:57:17.110482] [info] transaction done. 
   0: array(
      'ID' => 'john foo'
   )
```

*Expected result:*

```
{
"trace": [20]
0:  {
"date": "19-02-2016 16:57:17.104504"
"type": "info"
"message": "system done."
"ID": john foo
}
1:  {
"date": "19-02-2016 16:57:17.110482"
"type": "info"
"message": "transaction done."
"ID": john foo
}
...
```

Comment: Please show us an example of what you are expecting as result.

Comment: @hherger see my update

Comment: Is there a case where trace will have more than one object? If there is, please post a sample of source txt file and expected result.

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior complete example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

### Code

```
<?php
$file = 'test.log';

$content = array(); 
$content["trace"] = array();
$input = file_get_contents('test.log');

preg_match_all('/\[(.*)\][\s]*?\[(.*?)\][\s]*?(.*)[\s][^\']*\'ID\'[ ]*=>[ ]*\'(.*)\'/', $input, $regs, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($regs[0]); $i++) {
    $content['trace'][] = array(
        'date'    => $regs[1][$i],
        'type'    => trim($regs[2][$i]),
        'message' => trim($regs[3][$i]),
        'ID'      => trim($regs[4][$i]),
    );
}

// return $content;
echo '<pre>'; print_r($content); echo '</pre>';  // For testing only
$content = json_encode($content);                // For testing only
echo '<pre>' . $content . '</pre>';              // For testing only
```

### Result

PHP array:

```
Array
(
    [trace] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 19-02-2016 16:57:17.104504
                    [type] => info
                    [message] => system done.
                    [ID] => john foo
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 19-02-2016 16:57:17.110482
                    [type] => info
                    [message] => transaction done.
                    [ID] => john foo
                )

        )

)
```

Json object (string):

```
{
    "trace":[
        {
            "date":"19-02-2016 16:57:17.104504",
            "type":"info",
            "message":"system done.",
            "ID":"john foo"
        },
        {
            "date":"19-02-2016 16:57:17.110482",
            "type":"info",
            "message":"transaction done.",
            "ID":"john foo"
        }
    ]
}
```

Notes re. the RegEx:

- The file is read as a whole into a string variable ($input).
- The *preg_match_all(RegEx)* also scans the entire input.
- The code iterates over all its hits, where the groups contain these parts…

  - 1: date
  - 2: type
  - 3: message
  - 4: ID
- The RegEx in detail:

  ```
      \[       Match the character “[” literally
  (        Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
      .        Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *        Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  )
  \]       Match the character “]” literally
  [\s]     Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
  *?       Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
  \[       Match the character “[” literally
  (        Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
      .        Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *?       Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
  )
  \]       Match the character “]” literally
  [\s]     Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
  *?       Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
  (        Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3
      .        Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *        Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  )
  [\s]     Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
  [^']     Match any character that is NOT a “'”
  *        Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  'ID'     Match the characters “'ID'” literally
  [ ]      Match the character “ ”
  *        Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  =>       Match the characters “=>” literally
  [ ]      Match the character “ ”
  *        Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  '        Match the character “'” literally
  (        Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 4
      .        Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *        Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  )
  '        Match the character “'” literally
  ```

Comment: Nope, the result isn't in json content.. I post an example

Comment: Your earlier example was a php array. I add it to my answer.

Comment: I don't understand how the regex work.. could explain a bit? UPDATE: If I don't have the array, so have only this: `[19-02-2016 16:48:45.505547] [info] System done. ` No content is returned... @hherger

Comment: thanks for the regex explaination, there is a condition that I can insert? check my last comment for see the problem, maybe you don't see it.

Comment: Do you have mixed one-line entries (withou array...) **and** multi-line entries (with array...)?